# Using GPU error when use TensorFlow to train image

Tags: tensorflow, gpu

When I am runing a tensorflow image train job in the container tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-gpu, it doesn't work.

Error message:

```
Cannot assign a device for operation InceptionV3/InceptionV3/Conv2d_1a_3x3/Conv2D: Operation was explicitly assigned to /device:GPU:0 but available devices are [ /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0, /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:XLA_CPU:0, /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:XLA_GPU:0 ]. Make sure the device specification refers to a valid device.
[[node InceptionV3/InceptionV3/Conv2d_1a_3x3/Conv2D (defined at /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/layers.py:1057)  = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true, _device="/device:GPU:0"](fifo_queue_Dequeue, InceptionV3/Conv2d_1a_3x3/weights/read)]]
```

GPU info:
nvidia-smi
Mon Nov 26 07:48:59 2018
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 410.72       Driver Version: 410.72       CUDA Version: 10.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GT 630      Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 N/A |                  N/A |
| 25%   47C    P0    N/A /  N/A |      0MiB /  1998MiB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0                    Not Supported                                       |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+

Comment: Are you loading a previously trained model?

Comment: here is my step

mkdir download_data_flower
mkdir train_output

python download_and_convert_data.py --dataset_name=flowers --dataset_dir=download_data_flower

python train_image_classifier.py  --batch_size=64 --model_name=inception_v3 --dataset_name=flowers --dataset_split_name=train --dataset_dir=download_data_flower --train_dir=train_output

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you Tensorflow is not detecting any gpu as available but maps the operations to GPU:0. First try this:

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

And you'll get the available devices. Is there `/device:GPU:0` ?